# How to display page number in Bangla Language in LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice, language-support

I was trying to get the page numbers in [Bengali Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_%28Unicode_block%29) in LibreOffice. I've tried by enabling CTL from *Tools > Options > Language Settings > Languages*. Then from *Tools > Options > Language Settings > Comples Text Layout > General Options*, I selected Bengali (Bangladesh) from the Numerals. At this point, not only in the footer but also in the whole document, all numbers changed in to Bengali. But my aim was to change the language to Bengali of the page numbers in the footer only, not the whole document. To be frankly I did not find anything like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/384841/how-can-i-insert-page-numbers-in-different-language-in-word-2010) for LibreOffice, as there is in MS Word.

So, how can I change ONLY the page numbers into Bengali Language at the footer please?

**UPDATE:** 
I tried to modify the `Page Number` character style, by setting its CTL language to Bengali. But it did not either.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to modify the `Page Number` character style, setting its CTL language to Bengali. To do so:

1. Open "Styles and Formatting" (F11 or Menu `Format`);
2. Select the Character Styles (using the second button from the left, the one showing an `a`);
3. Select the `Page Number` style with a single left click;
4. Right-click, select `Modify...` select the `Font` tab. Now you can set the CTL language for that character style.

Comment: Did all the steps, but no luck!